# How to 4 side by side image align blogger mobile view vertical and dektop view horizontal

Tags: html, css, blogger

I have 4 images on my blogger site that I want to display horizontally on desktop and vertically on mobile.

Please tell me if there is any simple way to set this up.

Comment: Use flexbox and media queries.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use display grid or display flex in parent div of the images along with media query.

```
.parent-div{
display:grid;
grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
gap:10px}
```

Now add code for mobile

```
@media only screen and (max-width:767px){ 
.parent-div{grid-template-columns:auto}}
```

Let me know if it works ☺️.

Comment: Two precisions: 1. You can use `1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr` instead of `auto auto auto auto` to have pictures forced to the same width. 2. The `@media` part must come after the default one to have an effect.